# ajax does not work when @PathVariable use in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to add ajax function in one page. But it did not work with @PathVariable in spring mvc.
page1.jsp

```
<li><a href="page2/sss">WatchEvent</a></li>
```

1)It work properly 
In controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "page2/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView WatchEvent(@PathVariable("id")String id) {
System.out.println("In getplayback :"+id);   
 List<modelone> getdetails=Serviceone.detailsToUser(id);    
System.out.println("In getplayback from db:"+getdetails);    

return new ModelAndView("page2","getdetails",getdetails);    
}
```

Here details send to page2.
2))But in does not wordk.
   Page2.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("ready");
    var fun="event";

    var savedata = {    
            action:fun,             
            };
     $.ajax({
         url : "events",
         type : "POST",
         datatype:"json",
         data: savedata,
            error:function(){
                alert("Error");
            },
            success: function() { 
                alert("success");   

            }    
         });
});
</script> `
```

But does not go to the controller below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="events",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody  String GetSomeEvents(){    
System.out.println("In someevent********************");    
String todayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
System.out.print("today"+todayDate);
List<modelone> getlist=Serviceone.getSomeEvents();   

    return "success";   
 }
```

The result is alert error.

In firebug 
POST ......./page2/events

405 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try after modifying your action as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String GetSomeEvents(@RequestParam String action) {    
    System.out.println("In someevent********************");    
    String todayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
    System.out.print("today" + todayDate);
    List<modelone> getlist = Serviceone.getSomeEvents();   

    return "success";   
}
```

The modification is to add your request parameters to your action parameters.

Comment: In firebug POST ...projectname/page2/events
 
405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: I think there maybe something wrong with your URL. Isn't page2 mapped to your first request? Is there any RequestMapping on your Controller class?

Comment: In your ajax, try url: '../events'

Answer (score 0):

put this before ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
    scriptCharset: "utf-8", 
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
});
```

Comment: Do you mean 
           $.ajaxSetup({ 
         scriptCharset: "utf-8", 
         contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
     });
      $.ajax({
             url : "events",
             type : "POST",
             datatype:"json",
             data: savedata,
             error:function(){
              alert("Error");
             },
             success: function() { 
              alert("success"); 
        
             }  
             });
      
It is not working

Comment: Sorry. I think in your case, you have to change ajax method url. Now you have "events" but your controller is mapped like "page2/{id}". Dev-an answered your question :)

Comment: so.. cann't I use ajax function in page2.jsp?

Comment: In firebug POST ...projectname/page2/events
 
405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: if your page2 is not in the root directory, put "/projectname/events" in ajax call. or change your controller to "/events"

Comment: /events is not working. Then how how can I give /projectname/events in ajax call.

Comment: $.ajax({ url : "/projectname/events", type : "POST", datatype:"json", data: savedata, error:function(){ alert("Error"); }, success: function(){alert("success");}}); and change in your spring controller to "/events"